# What will be the upper and lower bounds of double integral in polar coordinate?

Tags: probability, integration

Starting with the following equation -
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0.21}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx $$
I've multiplied it by -
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0.21}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy $$
and got -
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0.21}^{\infty}\int_{0.21}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{2}}dy\,dx$$
Now if I want to convert it into polar form, what will be the upper and lower bounds of integration?
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \iint e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}r\,dr\,d\theta$$

---

Square root of the following produces correct probability -

$$\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{0.21\sec\theta}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}r\,dr\,d\theta$$

Comment: The bounds for that won't be pretty, you should probably rewrite it a bit first if you really want it in polar form. But what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Henrik Did you mean rewriting by $u$ substitution? I was trying to calculate probability with $z$ score 0.21.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Sketch the region $\{(x,y): 0.21\leq x < \infty, 0.21\leq y < \infty\}$

Comment: is it $0.21 \sec\theta\le r \le \infty$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}\le \theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$